# How to send chunks of a big 2D array to function for processing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 2D array storing image data using int. At this time it is 800x640 but that can change. I want to pass it to another function in 8x8 blocks for processing. I could actually just copy an 8x8 block of the array into a temporary variable and send that to the function and then copy result into another 800x640 array.

However, I want to the function to directly be able to access 8x8 blocks (which will be faster) if I give it the start xy coordinates within this 800x640 array. The problem is that using int** does not work. Also parameter declared as int[8][8] also does not compiled. What do I do? Right now I am writing the program in C++ but eventually shall have to write it in C as well.

Comment: How do you declare the main array? Why not pass the initial pointer and the starting coordinates? What do you mean `int** does not work? Have you tried solving the problem of a simple (1D) array first?

Comment: The main array is int x[640][800]. Need to pass 8x8 blocks of it to another function. The function parameter declared as int**y and int y[8][8] , both do not compile.

Comment: `int[][]` (2D array) is not the same as `int**`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the pointer to the original image with other parameters to the function and access each element of your `8x8` area inside the function.

Let's say this is your original `800x640` image:

```
int img[640][800];
```

Declare your fuction as:

```
void work_on_roi(int* img, size_t img_width, size_t img_height, int roi_x, int roi_y, size_t roi_width, size_t roi_height)
```

ROI stands for *region of interest*, a widely used term in the field of image processing. In your case, if you want to access roi with `(10,20)` as its top-left index, you can call this function with arguments as:

```
work_on_roi(img, 800, 640, 10, 20, 8, 8)
```

Inside this function, accessing the `(i,j)` element in the roi would be:

```
(img + (roi_y + j) * img_width)[roi_x + i]
```

You can utilize `roi_width` and `roi_height` parameter to check for integrity:

```
// before accessing (i,j) element of roi
assert(i < roi_width);
assert(j < roi_height);
assert(roi_x + i < img_width);
assert(roi_y + j < img_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the way you access the elements of the region will not change depending on how you have declared your array, the way you pass the array as a parameter will change depending on whether you have an actual 2D array or whether you have a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type*.

In the case of a true array declared similar to `int array[X][Y];` (where `X` and `Y` are defined constants) you can pass a `pointer to array of int [Y]`, (e.g. `(*array)[Y]`) as the parameter to your function.

In the case where array is will be converted to a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type*, when declared similar to `int **array;` or `int (*array)[z];` where you allocate pointers and blocks of each row, or one single block, respectively, you simply pass a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* (e.g. `int **array`)

Taking either case, you could change a region within the array with a simple function that iterates over the elements you wish to change. For example for the case where you have a 2D array as you specify, you could declare a function with logic similar to the following. (You could pass additional parameters as needed to effect whatever change you need)

```
enum { ROW = 10, COL = 10 };   /* constant definitions */
...
void chgregion (int (*a)[COL], int xs, int ys, int xn, int yn)
{
    int xlim = xs + xn,        /* xstart + xnumber_of_elements */
        ylim = ys + yn;        /* same for y */

    if (xlim > ROW) xlim = ROW;  /* protect array/block bounds */
    if (ylim > COL) ylim = COL;

    for (int i = xs; i < xlim; i++)
        for (int j = ys; j < ylim; j++)
            a[i][j] = 1;        /* change element as required */

}
```

Above the a pointer to an array of `COL` elements is passed along with the `x` and `y` starting position within the array and the number of elements in the region, e.g. `xn` and `yn`. A simple check is done to limit the region size to remain within the array bounds or bounds of a block of memory. If your array is actually a pointer-to-pointer-to-type, just pass `int **a` instead and pass the dimensions of the block of memory as additional parameters.

You can put together a simple test as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { ROW = 10, COL = 10 };

void chgregion (int (*a)[COL], int xs, int ys, int xn, int yn);
void prna (int (*a)[COL]);

int main (void) {

    int a[ROW][COL] = {{0}};

    prna (a);
    chgregion (a, 2, 2, 6, 6);
    putchar ('\n');
    prna (a);

    return 0;
}

void chgregion (int (*a)[COL], int xs, int ys, int xn, int yn)
{
    int xlim = xs + xn,
        ylim = ys + yn;

    if (xlim > ROW) xlim = ROW;
    if (ylim > COL) ylim = COL;

    for (int i = xs; i < xlim; i++)
        for (int j = ys; j < ylim; j++)
            a[i][j] = 1;

}

void prna (int (*a)[COL])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            printf ("%2d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array2d_region
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Let me know if this is what you were intending, or if what you are doing differs in some way. For further help, please post a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).